# Limiting File Types Logged by IIS (Reducing Log File Size)

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, asp.net, log-files, logging

Is there a way to say, for instance, **don't write an entry in IIS logs for specific file types**? The shear size of our logs today makes it difficult and cumbersome to filter them after the fact using LogParser and the like; we're only interested in logging managed requests (or a set of extensions that we can configure) - can this be done OOTB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explore [Advanced Logging for IIS 7.0 - Log Filtering](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/692/advanced-logging-for-iis-70---log-filtering/)